# Query Optimisation : Force MySQL to use 3 column compound index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a compound index on 3 columns. Now I want to execute the query based on only 2 columns, which both are not indexed. So the query takes long time to execute.

How to I make use of the compound index to alter my query?

Example : Table **Temp**

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 |

Now lets say I have compound index on column B, column C, and column D.

Now I want to select the rows based on only column b and column c

`SELECT column A from Temp WHERE column b = 'XYZ' AND column c = 'ABC';`

This doesnt use the index.

So is there a way I can make the query optimized so that the compund index is used.

I tried something like below, which does use the index but I want to remove this restriction since the value can be anything

`SELECT column A from Temp WHERE column b = 'XYZ' AND column c = 'ABC' AND column d LIKE 'P%';`

Comment: You could try using an index hint https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE Temp` -- We need to see the indexes that you currently have to explain why one might not be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html):

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to look up rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).

That means if your index is defined as (B, C, D) then query with condition like `B = '...' AND C = '...'` should use the index because (B, C) is leftmost prefix of (B, C, D). Query with conditions like `C = '...' AND D = '...')` or `B = '...' OR C = '...'` won't use that index.

Here is the [example on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8eRE8rEabTLG3gfZW2PbiJ/0)

Answer (score 1):

For

```
WHERE column b = 'XYZ' AND column c = 'ABC' AND column d LIKE 'P%';
```

You need

```
INDEX(b, c, d)   -- with `d` last
```

And get rid of `INDEX(b)` and `INDEX(b,c)`; they could get in the way of picking the optimal index.

I suspect you have some index that is "getting in the way".

Also, are they really string types?  Comparing INT and string or VARCHAR and numeric may cause trouble.

(I agree with Michal's answer.)